# MongoDB batch insert with unique index

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Suppose I have a list of documents that I want to insert.

The documents have structure as follow

```
{
  url: string,
  visited: boolean
}
```

I have a unique index on the `url` key.

When I insert the documents, if there is 1 duplicate found, the whole operation is aborted.

Is there a way that I can still use batch insert, and it will insert all that documents that are not duplicates?

As a workaround, I have to insert documents one by one, and I am afraid of the performance impact from the overhead of insertion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose I have a collection with unique index on the field named `a` as show by the output of [`.getIndexes()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.getIndexes/)

```js
> db.collection.getIndexes()
[
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                },
                "name" : "_id_",
                "ns" : "test.collection"
        },
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "unique" : true,
                "key" : {
                        "a" : 1
                },
                "name" : "a_1",
                "ns" : "test.collection"
        }
]
```

and the following array of documents:

```js
var docs = [ { 'a': 3  }, { 'a': 4 }, { 'a': 3 } ];
```

You can use the [`Bulk()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/#Bulk) API to insert bulk insert those documents into your collection but you need to use [*unordered operations*](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp/#db-collection-initializeunorderedbulkop) which allow MongoDB to continue processing the remaining write operations in the list even if an error occurs during the processing of one of the write operations.

```js
var docs = [{a: 3}, {a: 4}, {a: 3}]
var bulk = db.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
for(var ind=0; ind<docs.length; ind++) { 
    bulk.insert(docs[ind]); 
}
bulk.execute();
```

You will get an error message after execution of the query but non duplicates documents will be insert in your collection.

Here our collection was empty before the operation but after calling the [`bulk.execute()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk.execute/#Bulk.execute) `db.collection.find()` yields the following documents:

```js
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5629c5d1e6d6a6b8e38d013c"), "a" : 3 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5629c5d1e6d6a6b8e38d013d"), "a" : 4 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have to taken a look at using upsert?  https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.upsert/